# proof inequality . Thomae's function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I was looking at this post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430480/fx-x-if-x-irrational-and-fx-p-sin-frac1q-if-x-rational), I'm trying to understand but I do not understand this:

Let $x\in \mathbb{Q^+}$. How I can show $x > f(x)$.

The function $f$ is defined by $f(x)=x$ if $x$ is irrational, and $f(x)=p\sin\frac1q$ if $x=\frac{p}q$ is written in lowest terms.

Answer (score 1):

If $x>0$ then $\sin x<x$.  Therefore
$$
p \sin\frac 1 q < p\cdot\frac 1 q = \frac p q.
$$

Comment: Would I have to consider cases $p>0, q> 0 , p>q$ or $p>0, q> 0 , p<q$ or $p<0, q< 0 , p>q$ or ...

Comment: The conclusion holds only when $p/q>0$. We take $p$ and $q$ to be positive and coprime. Whether $p>q$ doesn't matter here. $\qquad$